# Высоконагруженные веб проекты

Tags: база-данных

Меня интересует следующий вопрос: какой язык программирования и базу данных (в общем технологии) вы посоветуете для разработки собственных высоконагруженных веб проектов.

Comment: Высоконагруженный это, в вашем понимании - какой? Предоставьте цифры, без них ваш ответ довольно абстрактен. Какая ориентированность проекта? И т.д. и т.п, это если вы хотите получить ответ **не** общего характера.

Comment: Честно говоря минус влепил бы за вопрос, но не люблю я этогого! Это равносильно что ковыряться в носу или в }|{опе, в носу вроде прикольно, а в
}|{опу уже и не очень полезишь... Вот собственно и выходит что одни скажут что на Java, а вторые что PHP. Для когото Java }|{опа а кому то PHP!

А я скажу так, если есть мозг, задумка будет реализована на любом допустимом для WEB языке, а лучше всего на том с которым подружилась голова!

Comment: @Palmervan, вообще-то у вашего ненаглядного PHP есть объективный недостаток - скорость исполнения.

Comment: не эксперт в PHP, но по-моему существует добрый десяток средств исправляющих этот недостаток путём кэширования и прочего, хотя если руки не из того места, то это бесполезно

Comment: @karmadro4 я где-то написал что рекомендую использовать PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Для высоконагруженных проектов советовал бы вам использовать такие компоненты:

```
Веб-сервер - NGINX (однозначно не апач!);
Серверный язык - Python (+ Django);
memcached сервер однозначно пригодится, а можно даже и несколько таких;)
СУБД - это уже вам выбирать, но лучше выбрать NOSQL-СУБД, например, MongoDB.
```

Хоть NOSQL СУБД становятся все более популярными, но тем не менее они крайне небезопасны( минус SQL-Injection, но плюс букет других дырок), а также используют специфичные языки доступа, которые придется также дерзать.  NOSQL-СУБД выдерживают куда более сильные нагрузки, но уязвимостей там предостаточно( если нужно об уязвимостях поконкретнее, то могу рассказать о них ).

Comment: использовать Python - один из самых медленных ЯП? обоснуйте, будьте добры.

Answer (score 1):

Опять... Хоть садись FAQ-пиши...

ВЫСОКО нагруженные системы собирают на кластерах.

На морде стоит nginx, который распуливает задания на кучу серверов.

Если у вас баннерная сеть - то она пишетс на С++ (раз в 5 быстрее РНР, раза в 2 java - хотя зависит от задачи я видел варианты когда java догоняла С++, а на математике РНР отставал почти в 40 раз)

Очередной вКонтакте нужно писать на том, что вы знаете, и под что найдете людей.
Особо узкие места лучше переписывать на Сях; но до какой-то поры кеширующий прокси вас спасет.

Грамотное построение БД гораздо важнее СУБД, которую вы юзаете.

В ряде задач текстовый файл оказывается быстрее, чем БД))

БД - ту которую знаете вы или ваш администратор/программист БД (есть же такой, правда?)

Если речь идет о Linux-серверах, я бы выбрал postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Морда безусловно на Java (JSP/Servlet). Servlet контейнеров много: да все тот же Tomcat - почему нет. Только надо его нормально прикрутить к приличному веб серверу. Ни CGI, ни PHP не дадут нормальной производительности (да простят меня поклонники PHP).

ASP неплох, но его проблема в сервере. В мире увы мало серверов с поддержкой ASP - не сравнить с Java.

В качестве БД можно взять на выбор либо Oracle либо SQL Server (MySQL при всем моем уважении не тянет приличные нагрузки).

Только никогда не ведитесь на модную виртуализацию серверов. Проверено на собственном горьком опыте. Лучше физических серверов ничего все равно пока не придумано. Да, дорого, но надежно.

Comment: Сервер написанный на Java, так-же, далеко не факт,что покажет адекватную производительность, конечно-же - причиной этому будет код. Что, собственно, актуально и в случае с PHP. Если все сделать "правильно" - не вижу абсолютно никаких проблем в случае использования PHP (ярким пруфом является, например, фейсбук).

Так что, лично я, мягко говоря не уверен в целесообразности применения слова "безусловно". Лучше написать так - одно из лучших решений( но однозначно не единственное, да и, банально, далеко не всегда в этом есть хоть какой-то смысл )

PS: не являюсь поклонником PHP, скорее наоборот

Comment: Конечно-же бывают задачи когда Java 100% предпочтительнее, но т.к. вопрос несет общий характер - рассматривается "обычный" интернет проект.

Comment: Perl, как мощный инструмент, хорошо зарекомендовал себя для меня, хоть я его и не глубоко изучил. Яндекс, на сколько я в курсе, пишут именно на Perl-е.

Comment: Почему "безусловно" на Java ?

Comment: Facebook, к слову, уже хрен знает сколько чистый РНР не использует.

Там стоит РНР->C++ транслятор, который даёт быстрый нединамический код.

БД думается мне - тоже не из стандартных исходников.

Comment: @SilverIce - кэп?

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, насколько мне известно, бОльшая часть Яндекса написана на С++. На перле, жабе и пр. - отдельные части.

Comment: Да какая разница на что потом переписывался facebook, яндекс и т.д. Начиналось то у фейсбука все с PHP у яндекса с Perl'a, вот и делайте выводы

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую платформу Go.

В пределе только исполняемый код Go + кэш памяти + база данных. Если проект требует выполнения SQL, то любую надежную SQL базу (MySQL, Postgres). Иногда удобно частично отказываться от чисто реляционной модели и хранить в SQL-базе JSON или XML.

Если не требует SQL, то Redis (память все больше дешевеет).

Answer (score 0):

Язык программирования не имеет принципиального значения. Важно чтобы ваше приложение могло масштабироваться. Примеры:

- PHP - Facebook, Badoo, вконтакте
- Java - одноглазики
- ASP(или что-то из этой серии от MS, я не силен в их технологиях) - microsoft.com и все их ресурсы.
- далее приводить примеры мне лень, важно чтобы используемый язык подходил для решения задачи, например писать чат на пхп не самая лучшая идея, написать можно, но ресурсов он будет отъедать гораздо больше чем чат написанный на node.js.

Опять же важно понимать, что перечисленные языки это как основной, также еще используются другие языки, например: вконтакте использует node.js для отдачи статусов пользователей.

База данных тоже не имеет особого значения, важны имеющиеся инструменты для ее масштабирования, из популярного нынче это: MySQL, Postgres, MSSQL Server, Oracle.
Примеры:

- MySQL - Facebook, Badoo, вконтакте
- Postgress - зона .com

Опять же тут речь идет об основной БД, есть также специализированные бд под другие задачи.

Общая суть всего этого поста, в хайлоаде важно масштабирование.